# Batch file to search common strings in two text files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have two text files, **all_codes.txt** and **downloaded_codes.txt** I wanted compare both text files and log if any string is missing in **downloaded_codes.txt**

**>all_codes.txt** will have the below strings

```
A1
A2
A3
```

**> Downloaded_codes.txt** will have the below strings

```
A1
A3
```

in this example, A2 is missing in **downloaded_codes.txt**, so I want to log "NO" in **log.txt**
if A2 was present in **downloaded_codes.txt**,then i want to log "YES" in **log.txt**

this is what I tried, am not getting proper result:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for / f "delims=~" % % h in (All_codes.txt) do
    for % % a in (downloaded_codes.txt) do(
        set found = false
        for / f "skip=2 tokens=*" % % b in ('findstr /i "%%h" "%%a"') do(
          if "!found!" == "false" ((echo YES > log.txt
            else(echo NO > log.txt)
            set found = true
          ))
        )
```

Comment: you have a very - hmm - creative syntax. But I'm afraid, `cmd` does not agree. This code will only produce syntax errors.

Comment: Stehpan is all right! not only there are unexpected spaces also there are missing opening braces (fourth line I'd expect a '(' after the 'do') and closing braces... also I'm not sure if the way you redirect to log.txt does what you want. A single > recreates the file each time. Delete the file once and then use >> to append.

Comment: spaces came when i pasted my code in the question,no space in my batch file.@dlanod i want the log file to be recreated each time.

Comment: have you considered using `comm` from unix utils?

Comment: @PA. no, i have not tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

findstr /V /G:Downloaded_codes.txt all_codes.txt > NUL
(if errorlevel 1 (echo YES) else echo NO) > log.txt
```

**EDIT**: This is an example session:

```
C:\> type test.bat
@echo off

findstr /V /G:Downloaded_codes.txt all_codes.txt > NUL
(if errorlevel 1 (echo YES) else echo NO)

C:\> type all_codes.txt
A1
A2
A3

C:\> type Downloaded_codes.txt
A1

C:\> test
NO

C:\> echo A3>> Downloaded_codes.txt

C:\> type Downloaded_codes.txt
A1
A3

C:\> test
NO

C:\> echo A2>> Downloaded_codes.txt

C:\> type Downloaded_codes.txt
A1
A3
A2

C:\> test
YES
```

Comment: Hi Aacini, i tried your code, it creates the log with "YES" even if some strings are not found in "downloaded_codes.txt".

Comment: See the edit in my answer. Please, try to duplicate my example session and then explain with more detail what is the problem...